# Jackson - override global NON_EMPTY on a specific field

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

My `ObjectMapper` is globally set to include only `NON_EMPTY` fields during serialization via `setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)`. However, I need to make an exception for one field only where I'd like to allow it to be serialized even when it is empty.

The field itself is somewhat complex, as it's of type `Map<String, List<MyObject>>` (I'm using Kotlin). I'd like to serialize entries which contain empty lists, for example the expected output would be `{"someKey": []}`.

Here's the whole class:

```
data class MyDataObject(
   @JsonValue val myField: Map<String, List<MyObject>>
)
```

I've tried annotating it with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)`, but this does not seem to do the trick. Do I *really* have to write a custom serializer, which I'm trying to avoid, or is there some way to annotate this field so that it serializes empty values as well? Thank you.

Comment: What are you annotating with `@JsonInclude`? The `class` or the field?

Comment: @Lino I've tried both. Strangely, `@JsonInclude` works when I apply it to a parent object which contains a list of `MyDataObject`.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but could it be that `@JsonValue` is somehow clashing with the `@JsonInclude` annotation. What happens, when you annotate `myField` with the `@JsonInclude` and remove the `@JsonValue`

Comment: It seems that it actually does.